# Django - Adding a custom button to generate a random password using APG

Tags: django

I want to add a custom button which will generate a random password using APG in one of the Django models.  I'm not sure which template I need to overwrite.  Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Here is the screen shot of the admin and the other panel where I want to create the button.

[image: The admin panel]

[image: The other panel]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than overriding the template, why don't you override the Admin model for your User and the password form and put in the link to generate the password there.  The link would likely trigger some javascript that could generate the random password for you, display it, and populate the field.  Here's some untested code...

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import NotRegistered

try:
    admin.site.unregister(User)
except NotRegistered:
    pass

class CustomUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'].help_text = "PUT YOUR CODE HERE"  

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = CustomUserForm
```